# Query MVC Web Api from another project while running on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Vis Stu solution that contains many projects. Two of these projects are a

```
MVC Web Application (Views, JS, CSS)
MVC Web API
```

Since these are their own projects, I need a way to query the Web Api via my web application.

In the JS I have a function that tries to get data from the Web Api

```
get: function (id) {
    var url = 'api/Employee/' + id;
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
        return data;
    };
    httpRequest.open('GET', url);            
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

If I build the Api solution and add in its localhost address to the ajax url (`http://localhost:50475/api/Employee/3`) I get the usually Cross Origin Not Allowed issue.

Is there a way to connect to this Api from another origin while I am in developing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding an assembly reference to your project? That will make projects accessible to each other in development.

In visual studio:
1. Go to the project that needs to have access to the API project
2. Right click references
3. Add reference 
4. Under Solution select the name of the project you're trying to access.

Comment: Hi, Yes I have added this reference. I am not trying to access the Web Api from the server side of my Web App. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I Think its because of different ports of WebApi and MVC Projects that visual studio assigned to them by default. you can change the default port bindings, You should set one unique port for both applications. Right click on project => properties => web and set the port.